# Detecting faint edges

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-recognition, edge-detection

I would need to find the rings in a picture of wood, however the lines are too faint and there is too much noise for the edge detection algorithms to give good results.

[image]

I've tried making the rings stand out more by increasing contrast, sharpening and some morphological operations. Then I've applied edge preserving smoothing filtering and tried several edge detection algorithms (sobel, canny..) but the results still look bad.

Comment: You can still post *links* to images. Someone with more rep will likely edit them directly into your question for you. And I don't think we can do much to help you without representative images.

Comment: agree with @breaker. you need to pose some image so that other people can help you

Comment: try shooting lines from the (wood) center to the outside and visualize the intensity. Probably the rings will be visible quite well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it works ok, but now the center point must be manually determined. It would need to be automatic and work for all similar pictures of wood. That's why I think I need edge detection to find the center of the wood or would there be some other approach to finding it?

Comment: These guys claim that they can detect faint edges: https://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Ofir_Fast_Detection_of_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Since your edges are smooth and large [Gabor Filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter) may be suited to your task. You will have to run the Gabor Filters for multiple orientations and frequencies over the whole image and choose the maximum response everywhere. This may, of course, lead to a significant computational cost.

Note: The Gabor Filters will find your smooth edges over noise because they integrate over a large number of pixels